# Dsolve 1D Maxwell Equations for time varying medium

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a toy model of 1D maxwell equations for a time-varying medium.
In this case the permittivity varies as $(1+t)^2$.

My PDE-systems looks like this

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(U(x,t)(1+t)^2)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(x,t)\\ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}V(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}U(x,t)$$

with initial conditions

$$U(x,0)=\sin(x)\\V(x,0)=-\cos(x)/2$$

The exact solution on the spatial interval $[0,\pi]$ is

$$U(t,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+t)^3}}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(1+t)}{2})\sin(x)$$
$$V(t,x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+t}}\left(-\cos(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(1+t)}{2})+\sqrt{3}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}\ln(1+t)}{2})\right)\cos(x)$$

Can Mathematica's Dsolve find this solution? I've tried to,but I failed. What am I doing wrong?
    Here's my attempt:

```
ClearAll[U, V]
sys = {
  D[U[x, t], t] == (D[V[x, t], x] - 2*(1 + t)*U[x, t])/(1 + t)^2,
  D[V[x, t], t] == D[U[x, t], x],
  U[x, 0] == Sin[x],
  V[x, 0] == -Cos[x]/2}
DSolve[sys, {U[x, t], V[x, t]}, {x, t}]
```

EDIT: first equation was wrong. Still I cant find a solution using Dsolve

Comment: The solution you give doesn't seem to satisfy your first equation: `Simplify[sys[[1]] /. {U -> Function[{x, t},  1/Sqrt[(1 + t)^3] Cos[(Sqrt[3] Log[1 + t])/2] Sin[x]], 
   V -> Function[{x, t},  1/(2 Sqrt[(1 + t)]) (-Cos[(Sqrt[3] Log[1 + t])/2] + 
        Sqrt[3] Sin[(Sqrt[3] Log[1 + t])/2]) Cos[x]]}, {t > 0, x > 0}]` gives Cos[1/2 Sqrt[3] Log[1 + t]] Sin[x] == 0

Comment: `DSolve[]'s` support for PDE equations is still somewhat limited,
 so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet. In yours case `Maple 2018` finds only general solution. Comparison Maple vs MMA:https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/pde_in_cas.htm

Comment: Thanks KraZug for your hint. @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Have you checked it with Maple using the corrections? Because I was thinking about trying Maple. I was told it's more flexible than Mathematica.

Comment: With yours  corrections `Maple` finds `only` general solution. Better is use MMA+Maple then You have the Force !!!

Comment: Ok. So obviously no software is able to give me a closed form solution for this. However, I'm pretty sure I could get quite close using the power series solution method, which Mathematica/Maple and even Matlab should be able to handle. Do you know if there's a built-in method in any of these ?